# Can I use a void pointer in C as an array?

Tags: c, arrays, undefined-behavior, void-pointers

I tried doing this in C and it crashes:

```
int nValue=1;   
void* asd;  
asd[0]=&nValue;
```

With the following error:

```
*error C2036: 'void**' *: unknown size  
error C2100: illegal indirection*
```

Can I use a void pointer in C as an array?

And if I can, what is the correct way to do so?

Comment: `void *` cannot be dereferenced but it can be converted between any pointer type. That being said, you never even initialize `asd` here...

Comment: What are you getting out of doing this?

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting that to do.  You can make an array of void pointers if you declared as `void* asd[5];`

Comment: @chris Im trying to debug a library which is giving me erros and I wanted to know if this is even possible.

Comment: @oldrinb so with what can it be initialized? with a string for instance and then use the brackets to modify each caracter?

Comment: That's not a crash, it's a compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write like this:

```
int main()
{
    int iv = 4;
    char c = 'c';
    void *pv[4];
    pv[0] = &iv;
    pv[1] = &c;

    printf("iv =%d, c = %c", *(int *)pv[0], *(char *)pv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use a void pointer in C as an array?

Nope.  You can convert to and from `void*`, but you cannot derference it, and it makes sense when you think about it.

It points to an unknown type, so the size is also unknown.  Therefore, you cannot possibly perform pointer arithmetic on it (which is what `asd[0]` does) because you don't know how many bytes to offset from the base pointer, nor do you know how many bytes to write.

On a side note, `asd` (likely) points to invalid memory because it is uninitialized.  Writing or reading it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Make sure you state `sizeof(void)` is undefined ;-)